# How to populate a drop down using string array list

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

Struts 1.x :
How to populate a dropdown using string array list? 
In the form bean (formbean) there are getter and setter methods for the list "blockIds" which is an string arraylist. For an example

```
ArrayList<String> blockIds = new ArrayList<String>();
blockIds.add("A");
blockIds.add("B");
```

What would be the jsp code which should look like the following after rendering.

```
<select name=“selectedItem”>
    <option value=“A”>A</option>
    <option value=“B”>B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populate drop down using array-list struts 1.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639799/populate-drop-down-using-array-list-struts-1-x)

Comment: Stop posting same question multiple times. And use correct tags.

Comment: Could you please answer this question. Seems like you are an expert in struts. I've posted the same question earlier  with a somewhat different description hoping for a solution. But no luck. So here I'm posting again. FYI I've deleted the previous one. 
If you could provide a solution I'll appreciate a lot.

Comment: Set this `ArrayList` in your form which is declared in action method. From the form you can get the list and using `<logic:iterate>` tag you can populate drop down.

Answer (score 0):

See like this,

```
public class TestAction extends Action {


public ActionForward populateDropdown(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws Exception {

            ArrayList<String> blockIds = new ArrayList<String>();
            blockIds.add("A");
            blockIds.add("B");

            MyForm myForm=(MyForm)form;
            myForm.setListMsg(blockIds);
            return mapping.findForward("success");
        }
}
```

And in HTML,

```
<html:select property="selectedItem" styleId="standard">
     <html:optionsCollection name="myForm" 
       property="yourList" label="label" value="value"  />
</html:select>
```

Even you can use `<logic:iterate>` tags for iterate.
Hope this helps